# Color/Opacity of a UIBarButtonItem image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I added two UIBarButtonItems to a toolbar.

The first I added using

```
initWithImage:style:target:action:
```

For the second, I created a UIButton, containing a UIImageView with the image set to the same used in the first example. I also made the image view slightly smaller that the button to allow room for a label. Then I created the BarButtonItem with

```
initWithCustomView:
```

I get very different renderings of the image:

[image]

What is going on here, and how do I get the image to be displayed as expected in the second example?

Note: I actually added the buttons in reverse order - in the image above, the first button is using initWithCustomView:

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation for initWithImage:style:target:action](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The images displayed on the bar are derived from this image [...] The alpha values in the source image are used to create the images—opaque values are ignored.

So, the image is being used as a mask.  This is the behavior you typically see used in toolbars, but is available here as well.  I guess you need to use custom views if you want the image pixels to be used on the bar.